# Determine if spring or fall and adjust time if DST or not

Tags: oracle, timezone, dst

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    to_date(to_char((from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(my_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ,'America/Edmonton')at time zone 'America/Vancouver'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') as Date_Column
FROM 
    my_table
```

It converts the time between MST to PST. This works most of the time except when daylight savings time occurs. Then a situation happens when in the clock moves forward an hour, and then since an hour is lost (for example 1:59 to the 3:00 am) then we are trying to convert a fictional time.

So I am aware of the issue, and I know Oracle will throw this error for that reason:

```
ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
```

I've looked all over the Internet for a possible work around but can't really find anything that works. I just want to modify my query so that it can tell what time of year it is and either do the conversation when the time exists, or handle the time somehow when it does not exists. Perhaps add the extra hour when it's missing, and remove it when it's the other time of year.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Is this an impossible problem?

Comment: Don't use `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(...),...)` just `CAST(... AS DATE)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that is representative of the issue; and your expected output. If you store values in the `UTC` time zone then you don't need to worry about skipping hours when there is a change for DST and can just apply the conversion to your output time zone as required when you display the value.

Comment: Unclear what you like to achieve. If you like to know whether your date falls into Daylight Saving Time, simply use `TO_CHAR(from_tz(CAST(my_column AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/Edmonton'), 'TZD') as DST`

Comment: Don't use `to_date(to_char(...(to_timestamp(to_char(...`, it's completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all the conversions you are using, just use `AT TIME ZONE`. You may need to take extra care depending on the data type of your column. The `AT TIME ZONE` functionality will always take into account daylights savings time.

- If your column is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, that would be ideal
  because you could just say `AT TIME ZONE 'PST'` and you would get the
  time in PST.
- If the column is the datatype `TIMESTAMP`, when you use `AT TIME ZONE` it
  will convert from the time zone of the current session to whatever
  you specify.
- If your column is a `DATE`, you will need to convert it to a `TIMESTAMP` first, then you can use the `AT TIME ZONE` function. Converting the `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP` will make the time zone 0:00 offset so be sure to account for that.

Another handy trick is to use `AT LOCAL`. This will convert the timestamp to the time zone of the current session. This may be handy if you have users of your application that are in multiple time zones.

**Example**

I am in the time zone -04:00 (East coast US) which is why that appears as my time zone in the examples below.

```sql
WITH
    my_table
    AS
        (SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 8:00:00 -7:00'     AS ts_with_tz,
                TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 8:00:00'           AS ts,
                DATE '2021-01-01' + (8 / 24)             AS dt
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT 1     AS example_num,
       t.ts_with_tz,
       t.ts,
       t.dt
  FROM my_table t
UNION ALL
SELECT 2     AS example_num,
       t.ts_with_tz AT TIME ZONE 'PST',
       t.ts AT TIME ZONE 'PST',
       TO_TIMESTAMP (t.dt) AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
  FROM my_table t
ORDER BY 1;
```

**RESULT**

```
   EXAMPLE_NUM                                             TS_WITH_TZ                                                     TS                                                     DT
______________ ______________________________________________________ ______________________________________________________ ______________________________________________________
             1 01-JAN-21 08.00.00.000000000 AM -07:00                 01-JAN-21 08.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK       01-JAN-21 08.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK
             2 01-JAN-21 07.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES    01-JAN-21 05.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES    31-DEC-20 09.00.00.000000000 PM AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

Comment: I think `t.ts AT TIME ZONE ...` and `TO_TIMESTAMP (t.dt) AT TIME ZONE ...` are not very smart. Better specify the time zone explicitly, i.e. `FROM_TZ(t.ts, 'US/Pacific') AT TIME ZONE ...` or `FROM_TZ(Cast(t.dt AS TIMESTAMP),'US/Pacific') AT TIME ZONE ...`

Comment: Timezones like `-07:00` of course do not take into account daylights savings time. `TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 8:00:00 -7:00' + 180*interval '1' day` has still an offset of `-07:00`

Comment: You should not use `TO_TIMESTAMP(t.dt)` because it relies on session NLS-Parameters. Actually it runs `TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(t.dt, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')), SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT'))`. It fails if these two formats are different.